# Can "mislead" be accompanied by "that-clause"?

Tags: sentence-structure

"The fallacy of false choice **misleads that** the choices which have been made explicit **exhaust** the sensible alternatives."

Q1. The structure of the above sentence is "Subject + misleads that-clause". I know S misleads 'you' or 'us'. But can S mislead 'that-clause', too? If possible, what does that above sentence mean?

Q2. What's the exact meaning of "exhaust" here? Does it have any other meaning than "to make tired" or "to run out of something"?

Q3. Would you rephrase that sentence for me to understand easily?

Q4. Just to double check, suppose I put it this way, "He is misleading that she is an honest girl." What does this sentence mean?
Is he misleading people by saying that she is not honest, even though she is honest? Or  Is he misleading people by saying that she is honest, even though she is not honest? Or something else?

Comment: I don't know or care about the "grammaticality" of your examples, but they're completely ***unidiomatic***, so you should probably just forget the whole idea. On the other hand, even though I think it's a bit clunky, I don't think attaching a "that- clause" to "mislead" is completely unacceptable ***if you include the direct object*** (the person/s misled). I only found one syntactically relevant written instance of "misled him that" in Google Books, and it's not that good, but...

Comment: *[someone] [**misled him that**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22misled+him+that+his+demand+for+counsel%22) his demand for counsel prior to authorizing suspension of a motorist ' s license to taking the test should be regarded as an unjustified drive...* From an "official" text, but not well written, I would say.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think there will be a grammatical rule to provide certainty here, so in the final analysis it'll just be the (hopefully, unanimous) OPINION of people here that the usage being queried ***should be avoided***.

Comment: Note that there's nothing syntactically wrong with *The fallacy of false choice **misinforms people that** the choices which have been made explicit exhaust the sensible alternatives.* Also note that whereas in *some* contexts, ***to mislead*** can be used intransitively (i.e. - without specifying ***who*** is being misled), you can't do that with ***to misinform*** (which works fine with a "that- clause", and obviously should be considered as a suitable "unproblematic" alternative verb for OP's context).